# How can a manufacturer verify a circuit design?

Tags: integrated-circuit, jtag, reverse-engineering, verification

Could anyone tell me what  means (**other than reversing**) available to manufacturer of integrated circuits (latest Intel PC CPU's) that would allow them to verify that the actual design on die is exactly the same and identical to the blue prints or design circuit code ? I have heard of JTAG but don't fully understand this technology.

**[Why the Question]** The basis of the question is how can a manufacturer confirm and verify that no say RF based backdoors have been added to their design by its own circuit designers or by the factories.

Comment: That's an awful lot of questions and statements.  Maybe rephrase your question to make it more focused.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no technical solution to this problem for chip vendors who outsource their fab. As I recall, DARPA was interested in this several years ago.

Comment: Imagine testing a chip against RF backdoors by sweeping the 2.4GHz ISM band for 1 minute, and the test detects no response from the chip. Is there truly nothing sneaky there, or is there a sneakier cheat circuit waiting for a 2 minute RF burst before it responds? No matter what kind of test you can think of, the "enemy" could surely also think of the same test, and figure a sneaky way to beat that test. The typical arms race escalation. Best you can do is find a level of testing where it is no longer worthwhile to cheat -- but that costs more testing resources.

Comment: Intel can be quite sure that their chips are right as they own and run the fabs, the design teams are HUGE, when a single fab line costs $10 billion, you can bet that they test every possible aspect to make sure things are setup right. *However*, fabless manufacturers have to trust that their chosen foundry isn't going to fiddle with their designs and add in some nefarious subsystem. Thankfully, RF and digital CMOS don't play nice together, to the point that dual dies are quite common. I wouldn't worry about intel, samsung, ibm etc. but I'm sure there are some dodgy small time fabs out there

Comment: @Tom *However, fabless manufacturers have to trust that their chosen foundry isn't going to fiddle with their designs and add in some nefarious subsystem* I work at a fabless design company and **only** a company that didn't have a clue what they're doing would **not** notice changes to their design. Adding some RF part unnoticed is out of the question because one look under a microscope is enough to see that. For digital that is more difficult but as testvectors would change, only an idiot would not notice. Also there's trust. If a fab does this, you cannot trust them anymore.

Comment: High end processors are mostly cache, so the process is optimized for SRAM production. It is true that an RF backdoor would be essentially impossible to add, and RF systems require antennas, etc. But the greater question of whether SOME kind of backdoor could be added is one of great concern to certain people.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Yeah, I realise I may have made the prospect of an altered design seem much more likely than it really is, I was trying to make the point that the likelyhood of something like this would be greater with a fabless design, but I realise we're talking about a 1 in a billion vs. 1 in a trillion chance. But you're right, with the kinds of costs involved, a company would be pretty silly not to check their designs, but with a small inexperienced startup or the like, you can almost see it happening, *almost*...

Answer (score 1):

Integrated circuit designs are done in teams because it is a very complex task. It would be very difficult for a single design engineer to hide something. A number of people would have to work on such a conspiracy.

From a designer's point of view an RF block is something completely different than a digital block. It looks completely different in the chip layout and would stick out like a sore thumb during a closer inspection of the fabricated chip. Not to mention the fact that additional circuitry would require additional die area and it would be very difficult to add something to a chip that had already been brought into a nice rectangular shape.

During the manufacturing process failures can happen and it actually has to be expected that the chip that comes out of the fab does not have to intended functionality. For this reason chips are tested on die level as well as on package level. Some of the methods (-> google) are Iddq testing, ATPG and BIST.
If some irregularities are discovered a broad range of failure analysis methods is available for further analysis.

Chips that emit RF could also be discovered during compliance tests (FCC/CISPR) where emissions are measured in an anechoic chamber. Sometimes chips are the source of EMI problems and closer inspection using for example surface scan can be used to locate the area on a chip that generates EMI.

Finally, I think that almost everything is possible, however in this case it would be a very difficult endeavor.

Comment: I worked in this industry.  I agree that the teams are important but IMHO a single designer could add a hidden function in a design.  Functional verification is done against expected good behaviors - protocol errors are also verified agains error handling, but not every protocol error can be checked.
Formal functional verification (done for selected parts) would identify such extra functionnality and qualification of the verification setup may also lead to the identification of extraneous functions.
Exploiting a backdoor may be more difficult than putting it in.

Answer (score 0):

For the matter of backdoor probably the correct answer is you never know for sure. I mean, there is always a possibility of conspiracy or even a mistake.

In security the threat is measured by time or money investment required to breach the defense, in no model absolute security is assumed.